# To calculate the effect on right ventricular function in patients of nasal polyposis , randomised control trial

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have to do one point blind random control trial on patients  of nasal polyposis ... i have to see the effect  on right ventricular function  of polypectomy  before and after 3 months of surgery....  we have two groups on medical and other is medical plus surgery.  Once the patients diagnosed with nasal polyposis we will great the patient with fluticasone  nasal spray for 21 days and then patients will be radomised either to continue medical treatment or randomised to surgery. And right ventricular function has to be evaluated at the time of  diagnosis and after  three months in both groups. The person doing echocardiography for RVF  has to be blinded about the group. I want to know how to calculate the sample size  ans stastical  hypothesis..

Answer (score 0):

**Two-sample, two-sided t test.** It seems you will be doing a 2-sample t test of $H_0: \mu_M = \mu_S$ against
$H_a: \mu_M \ne \mu_S.$

**Information required for power computation.** Crucial inputs to a power computation are:

(a) significance level $\alpha,$

(b) estimated population standard deviation of Medical and Surgical groups (which one hopes are about the same), and

(c) the difference in the measure of ventricular function you want to be sure to detect (if present).

**Current assumptions.** I suppose (a) will be $\alpha = 0.05.$ Then in order to do a reasonable power transformation, one needs to have reasonable estimates of (b) and (c). Actually,
it is the ratio of (c) to (b) that matters. Absent more specific information,
I will assume you want to detect a difference as large 1.5 times the SD.

**Power curves.** Most statistical software has programmed procedures for finding sample size necessary to get a suitable power (probability of being able to reject if a difference of desirable size is present). Below is a relevant figure from
Minitab software.

[image]

**Conclusions?** If you think I have made reasonable guesses, then this figure should give you
a good idea what sample size between 10 and 40 subjects *per group* would be
enough for your study. I have assumed the population SD might be 
around $4$ (in appropriate units) and the graphs include a span up to $\pm 8$ units. It would not be difficult to do another power computation
for different assumptions.

These power computations assume that data are approximately normally distributed.
For smaller samples the assumption of normal data may be more crucial. If you
have access to previous measurements on ventricular function, it would be
helpful to know whether they tend to be normally distributed and what the standard deviation has been in previous studies.